# Pebble unable to render colon from font

Tags: pebble-sdk

I am creating a Pebble time watchface that is Colorado Avalanche themed. I am using the NHL Edge Colorado font from the "Hockey (NEW!)" zip on this site http://eriqjaffe.50webs.com/.

When I test my watchface, the numbers show up just fine but my colon displays as a rectangle. How do I get my colon to show as a colon and not a rectangle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The font *does* include the colon, so that's good news. You're having a problem with character set at some level. I'm not sure if there are explicit UTF-8 settings, but that may be part of it.

Alternatively, try using straight ASCII. decimal 58 or hex 0x3A is a : character.

```
char[2] buffer=" ";
buffer[0]=58;
```

then print that buffer.

or

```
  time_t temp = time(NULL); 
  struct tm *tick_time = localtime(&temp);
  static char buffer[10];
  strftime(buffer, sizeof("00:00"), "%I %M", tick_time);
  buffer[2]=58;
```